# How does the `||` work in Perl?

Tags: perl, logical-operators, short-circuiting

How does the `||` works in Perl? I want to achieve c style `||` operation.

```
@ARRAY=qw(one two THREE four);

$i=0;

if(($ARRAY[2] ne "three")||($ARRAY[2] ne "THREE"))         #What's the problem with this
{
   print ":::::$ARRAY[2]::::::\n";
}


while(($ARRAY[$i] ne "three")||($ARRAY[$i] ne "THREE"))       #This goes to infinite loop

{

 print "->$ARRAY[$i]\n";
   $i=$i+1;

}
```

Comment: If you want to know how something works, read the documention: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or

Comment: You should look at the `perltidy` script that will make your stuff much easier to read and maintain. You also REALLY need to be using `use strict; use warnings;`. If you don't, you will hit hundreds of avoidable issues that perl will tell you about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works exactly the way you thought it would. However, you have a thinko in your condition. Every value is either not one value *or* not another value.

I believe you might have wanted

```
if ($ARRAY[2] ne 'three' && $ARRAY[2] ne 'THREE') { ...
```

or

```
if ($ARRAY[2] eq 'three' || $ARRAY[2] eq 'THREE') { ...
```

You might also want some case-insensitive way of comparing, like

```
if (lc $ARRAY[2] ne 'three') { ...
```

or possibly a case-insensitive regexp match.

Comment: thanks @rafi. Some times little mistakes take lot of time to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Two general points. (1) Your Perl scripts should include `use strict` and `use warnings`. (2) In most situations, you can iterate directly over an array, avoiding subscripts entirely. An example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ARRAY = qw(one two THREE four);

for my $item (@ARRAY){
    last if lc $item eq 'three';
    print $item, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `($ARRAY[2] ne "three") || ($ARRAY[2] ne "THREE")` the `||` is a logical `or`, which means it returns true if at least one of the two expressions is true. Well, it checks the first one and if it is true, it even does not check the second one. And in this case the whole will be true anyway, since `$ARRAY[2]` cannot be equal to both strings.

Well, it is just like in C I believe. What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

`while(($ARRAY[$i] ne "three")||($ARRAY[$i] ne "THREE"))` :

the expression `$ARRAY[$i] ne "three"` always evaluates to true. Therefore you have an infinite loop. The `||` operator has short-circuit behavior so the second expression is never evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ($ARRAY[$i] ne "three") || ($ARRAY[$i] ne "THREE"))
```

This is going to be true in every case. It's either going to be not "three" or not "THREE". You want `&&`.